# How to force Windows Update to reflect pause window applied with Powershell Script?

Tags: windows, powershell

How could I force Windows update to reflect regedit change regarding an update pause?

I'm currently using command below to pause the Windows Updates:

```
 Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings' -Name 'PauseUpdatesExpiryTime' -Value (Get-Date).AddDays(35)
```

Afterwards the Windows Update is not reflecting the pause, I verified the Regedit had the correct pause window. Is there a way to force the Windows Update in Settings menu to reflect the regedit change?

Comment: You may try to broadcast a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) message. Example: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSCI/1.0.4/Content/core%5Cutils%5CUpdate-EnvironmentVariables.ps1 Please also add a Windows version tag, such registry keys tend to be specific to Win versions.